# Svmono and "real page dimensions''

Tags: dimensions, sv-classes, cropmarks

I'm writing a document with the Springer's template `svmono`. Clearly the margins and more generally  the page layout is automatically setted. Despite this, the output file is  displayed as an  A4 pdf file. I want to print my document ''like a book'', namely in a format that is smaller than an A4 paper; so which is the best way to set the page dimensions? Clearly the text should result centered into the page.

**Addenda:** 
I've tried this solution:

```
\documentclass[envcountsame,envcountchap]{svmono} 
\usepackage{subfiles}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[bottom]{footmisc}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{stmaryrd}   
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathrsfs} 
\usepackage{amssymb} 
\usepackage[all,cmtip]{xy}
\usepackage{faktor}
\usepackage[colorlinks={true},linkcolor={blue},citecolor={blue}]{hyperref}
\usepackage[frame,width=15truecm,height=23.5truecm,center]{crop}
\begin{document}
 blablabla
\end{document}
```

but in this way the paper is cutted. I'd like to mantain the above dimensions (i.e. `width=15truecm,height=23.5truecm`) but with some crop marks to underline the ''real'' printable area.

Comment: Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: You are right. I've edited the question and I apologize.

Comment: There is no need for an apology, don't worry about that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The key to a possible solution is the `geometry` package, which sets the corresponding dimensions. Including `crop` **after** `geometry` is strongly advised.

```
\documentclass[envcountsame,envcountchap]{svmono} 
\usepackage{subfiles}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[bottom]{footmisc}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{stmaryrd}   
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathrsfs} 
\usepackage{amssymb} 
\usepackage[all,cmtip]{xy}
\usepackage{faktor}
\usepackage[colorlinks={true},linkcolor={blue},citecolor={blue}]{hyperref}
%\usepackage[frame,width=15truecm,height=23.5truecm,center]{crop}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[a4,frame,axes,cross,pdftex,center]{crop}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\geometry{width=15cm,height=23.5cm}
\begin{document}
\blindtext[10]
\end{document}
```

Please use the options to crop at will, I just used them to show the frame etc.
I also added `blindtext` to show the effect. The screenshot below is itself 'cropped' ;-)

Perhaps, there is also some need to change the geometry, I did not print my solution and checked the crop mark.

[image]

Comment: I hope, my solution fits your needs...

Comment: Does `a4` in `\usepackage[a4,frame,axes,cross,pdftex,center]{crop}` need to be there?

Comment: @Geremia: You could exchange it to an other wellknown paper format..., but the crop marks may appear at the edges of the page.