# Draw user defined print margin

Tags: margins, koma-script

How can one draw a box on each page (KOMA class srcreprt) to
show a user defined print margin. E.g. the box should be 25 mm
from each page margin (which might be different from the actual
layout setting which can be shown with \usepackage{showframe})

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{showframe}

\begin{document}

\Blinddocument

\end{document}
```

Comment: This is related to http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/171459/svmono-and-real-page-dimensions/171480#171480 and the `crop` package

Answer (score 4):

Try this code:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\usepackage{eso-pic}

\AddToShipoutPicture{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
    \draw[line width=1pt]
         ($(current page.north west) +(25mm,-25mm)$)
         rectangle
         ($(current page.south east) +(-25mm,25mm)$);
\end{tikzpicture}%
}
\begin{document}

\Blinddocument

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

With `background`:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{background}
\backgroundsetup{
angle=0,
scale=1,
opacity=1,
color=black,
contents={%
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
\draw ([xshift=25mm,yshift=25mm]current page.south west) rectangle ([xshift=-25mm,yshift=-25mm)]current page.north east);
\end{tikzpicture}%
}
}

\begin{document}
\Blinddocument

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

After a few modification of the karlkoeller's code I came up with the
solution I was looking for:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\usepackage{eso-pic}

\AddToShipoutPicture{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
    \draw[line width=1pt]
         ($(current page.north west) +(25mm,-25mm)$)
         rectangle
         ($(current page.south east) +(-25mm,25mm)$);
\end{tikzpicture}%
}

\begin{document}

\Blinddocument

\end{document}
```

Comment: Sorry, I didn't read "from page margin". I've modified my answer.

Comment: @karlkoeller Eh!. I too followed suit. Damn. :)