# Add printing border

Tags: book-design, printing, publishing, cropmarks

I want to add to my document a kind of a border (actually I don't know how I should call it) that you can see below. It's probably helpful for [book folding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Book_folding) or [bookbinding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bookbinding).
[image: LDD3 front page]
This example comes from [*Linux Device Drivers, Third Edition*](https://lwn.net/Kernel/LDD3/). How can I do it?

Comment: Perhaps the `crop` package will be useful

Comment: An addition to @ChristianHupfer 's comment, here's a very similar question with the same advice (`crop` package): http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/181078/ **EDIT** Christian also gave the same comment there :) and recommended http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/171459/ (@2014).

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner: I even can't remember what I did yesterday, so I can't remember what I wrote two years ago ;-)

Comment: That's exactly what I needed. Thank you! :-)